# How to do SNMP using SNMP4J with incuding MIBS?

Tags: java, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

my snmp string is

```
snmptrap -Ci -Ls 7 -r1 -t10 -v 2c -c  100.100.100.104 00000 NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification UCD-DEMO-MIB::ucdDemoPublicString s {"m":"17","time":"1388559297","date":"1388559297"}
```

how can i send this string uning SNMP4j library please  help me to call this in java

i have this code what change need to do for sending above string

```
try {
            // Create Transport Mapping
            TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
            transport.listen();

            // Create Target
            CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
            comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
            comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
            comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress("100.100.100.104" + "/" + 162));
            comtarget.setRetries(2);
            comtarget.setTimeout(5000);

            // Create PDU for V2
            PDU pdu = new PDU();

            // need to specify the system up time
                    long sysUpTime = 111111;
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new TimeTicks(sysUpTime)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID(trapOid)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress, new IpAddress(ipAddress)));

            // variable binding for Enterprise Specific objects, Severity (should be defined in MIB file)
            //pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification")));
            //pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("UCD-DEMO-MIB::ucdDemoPublicString")));
            pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);



            Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
            System.out.println("Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);
            snmp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error in Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            System.err.println("Exception Message = " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: You're welcome. :) Noise deleted.